# Creating toggle layers in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am very new to Leaflet and coding and I am having some problems creating a map.

I have been able to create a map showing all my points but I would like to be to be able to distinguish between all different types of cheese via toggleable layers.

[image: Cheese Map Locations]

I have tried to use the solution shown in [Leaflet: How to create toggleable overlays from a single GeoJSON FeatureCollection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169011), with no success.

This is my test [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61xs94n8/2/), could you tel me what I am doing wrong?

Also I have all the Geodata saved in a cheese_map.geojson, that I would like to refer to in the javaScript rather than having 1000 lines of it.

---

I have managed to progress on this creating individual layers for each cheese type and using different icons as markers.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried something like this http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/ ?

Answer (score 1):

1. The GeoJSON data that you provide in your JSFiddle is invalid at line 944: the `"    Style"` property key uses an invalid first character. You can use GeoJSON linting tools to help you check your data (e.g. http://geojsonlint.com/)
2. With JavaScript, you can call separate files using "AJAX" methods. For example, you could use jQuery's [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method to load your GeoJSON data in a separate file and process it. Make sure you understand the [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) aspect of JavaScript when going this way.

```js
jQuery.getJSON('./cheesemap.json', function (geojsonData) {

  // Process the geojsonData...

});
```

Live demo (without the "all points" option): https://plnkr.co/edit/rf2JDe3RfF9p8Xm3Ga98?p=preview